# Узнать путь к файлу, который сейчас выполняется

Tags: java

Что-то вроде установщика. В папке лежат файлы и `.jar` файл.
Неизвестно где будет папка. В `.jar` нужно из этой папки скопировать файлы. Как указать путь к ним для команды `files.copy()`?
В cmd можно без указания пути обращаться к таким файлам. Так как по умолчанию файлы ищутся в папке, откуда запущен скрипт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите варианты здесь: [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file).

Например, вариант из ответа [@Benny Neugebauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451634/benny-neugebauer):

```
//подставить название своего класса для получения источника
CodeSource codeSource = YourMainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
//Путь к JAR
File jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath());
//Путь к папке
String jarDir = jarFile.getParentFile().getPath();
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!